# Does Rhino have function convert its script to java source code?

Tags: java, function, rhino, code-conversion

Does Rhino have function convert its script to java source code? I want to convert Rhino script to java source code.

Comment: You want a translator from JavaScript to Java? Where have you looked?

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: Hi Bob and Philipp. I want to know what rhino do when runnig my script. In addition I think Java source code is more reliable than Rhino's(sorry it's no reason). So I want to convert Rhino source code to Java's. But it is too difficult for me to read and realize Rhino source code ,because my programming skill is very low and I think I don't need to realize all about Rhino. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think is not possible do that. You need to read the Rhino documentation and if you know a little bit of java you can do this.

but if you want to learn some code of rhino writing by other person you can do this when a few breakpoints.

Java:

```
public void CheckMe(Object obj) {
   // breakpoint here -> 
   System.out.println(obj);

}
```

Javascript or (Rhino file):

```
function doMe() {
   // here you can pass any object to java 
   javaInjectedContext.CheckMe(some_object); 

   // e.g.
   var hola = { "huup" : 202, mikaSp : "jjuu"};
   javaInjectedContext.CheckMe(hola);
}
doMe();
```

and when your are debuggin you will check each line.. the content of each object (like each step) so you can check class type or value, etc.